# update field if change

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller with typical views (Index, Create, Edit, Delete). In index I show a list of object attributes.
I.E. Books

```
===============================
ID || Title || Author || % Read
-------------------------------
1  || Haaa  || Oksdkds||   90
===============================
```

Ihe field %Read can change while viewing the page. Is there any way to check via ajax if this field has changed, and update it?

Comment: In a web environment, I don't see any other way than a loop with a timer wich will query server for changes  and update if needed (with ajax)  every x second (for example). You may lookk at http://pusher.com , or search for `Long polling`

Comment: Did u find the below answer useful ?

Comment: Yes, but there was a problem. There were many items, and with this solution I had to implement an array of values to notify and check. So at last, as my application is an intranet app with very few users, and very few and slow changes, I did a refresh each 10 seconds. But if my application had a lot of users, I´d have used your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is below :

Use Timer to keep updating the Read like below

```
setInterval("YourFunctionName();", 1000); //Time is in milliseconds
```

**JQuery/JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function YourFunctionName() {
        var Istrue = false;
        $.ajax({
            url         :   "@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName")",
            contentType :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType    :   "json",
            type        :   "GET", //For non complex data only
            data        :   JSON.stringify({ param1:'Value1' })
        }).done(function(Result) { 
            //Update the Read Field here like below
            $('ID').html(Result.Value)
        })
        .fail(function() {
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ActionName()
{
    return Json(new { Value = 10 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```